# Confused about use of return status code shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

In a book I'm reading the below line

```
ls "$1" 2>/dev/null | grep "$1" 2>/dev/null 1>&2
```

when written in a script - by the book it says "*The command is executed to check whether the file passed as the command line argument exists. The standard error is redirected to `/dev/null` (the unix black hole), and standard output is redirected to standard error by using `1>&2`. Thus, the command does not produce any output or error message; its only puprose is to set the command returns status value `$?`.*"

But running the code:

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
```

would I not know it otherwise, I have tried without the cmd at beginning and with it as well with having no impact  on the results. I'm sure the author would have written for some purpose. I cannot just figure what?

[image: near complete code]

Comment: Can you add more context to the book quote?

Comment: would a screenshot work?

Comment: Kindly check now. Does it help?

Comment: Is there a question here?  The first line produces no output, just set the return status.  The second line checks the return status, but is incomplete and also produces no output, so you can't see any visible effect of that check.

Comment: @ChrisDodd check update

Comment: UNIX the TextBook second edition Sarwar Koresky Sarwar

Comment: From the photograph I can already see three dubious constructs.  Perhaps you should try a different book.  (Or perhaps the author explains later why his program is bad?)

Comment: `test -e "$1"` would be the idiomatic way to test whether a file exists.  `if [ -e "$1" ]; then ...` would be the idiomatic way to use it in a conditional.  Shell scripts almost never need to examine `$?` explicitly although it would perhaps make sense to learn that the variable exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a very bad book, giving code that noone sane would ever write to poorly illustrate concepts that are generally used in completely different ways in shell scripts.

The line:

```
ls "$1" 2>/dev/null | grep "$1" 2>/dev/null 1>&2
```

is as described -- it has no visible effect other than setting the return code.  Is your question about what this does in detail to get a return code or something else?

The line:

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
```

is an incomplete fragment that checks the return code of the previous command.  It's incomplete as there is no `then` or `fi`, without which the shell will reject it as a syntax error and not do anything (if you type the above at a prompt, you'll get the secondary prompt, telling you the shell is waiting for more input to get a complete command).  So without more code there's no apparent effect.  Something more complete like:

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo YES; else echo NO; fi
```

would output `YES` or `NO` based on that return code.

A more sensible way of doing the 6 lines starting with the `ls` would be:

```
    if [ ! -e "$1" ]; then
        echo "$1: not found"
        exit 1
    fi
```

---

As to what the `ls` line actually does, it runs `ls` (list files) with the name in `$1` as an argument, then uses `grep` to search that listing for the same filename.

So if the file does not exist, ls gives an error and outputs nothing, so the grep fails (setting `$?` to 1).  If the filename exists and is not a directory, the grep will succeed (setting `$?` to 0).  Finally, if the filename exists and is a directory, it will search the contents of that directory, looking for any file or subdirectory with the same name as a substring -- which is probably just a bug.  In addition, if `$1` is a string beginning with `-`, it will do something fairly useless and unpredictable.

Overall, a prime example of a shell script that should never be written -- any student that turned in such a monstrosity should get an immediate F.

Comment: Chris I have tried to upload complete code as screenshot, I'm stuck why is this "ls "$1" 2>/dev/null | grep "$1" 2>/dev/null 1>&2" needed to check value of $?....

Comment: @asad: It's not -- it's a random useless command that sets the value of `$?`, as all commands do.  The `if` checks the value of `$?` that it sets.

Comment: Chris I believe you must have a good recommendation for a book to learn unix shell programming ?

Comment: With the screen... well, bookshot, it's alright.  sh will leave the return code of the *last* command run (grep) as `$?`, which is then checked by the if - but the `then` is on a separate line.  context is very important to us, sometimes it's not a single line that explains it all

Comment: the `if ` command extends all the way up to the `fi` command -- the shell will keep reading lines until it gets the `fi`, and won't execute anything until then.  Within the `if`..`fi` command, newlines and `;` are exactly the same.